# no such file to load -- bundler/setup (Ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to get a rails 3.0.5 app up and running at http://blastoserver.com/. You can see the errors there. (backtrace)

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you set your RUBY_ENV to production?

Comment: production is the default environment for passenger.

Comment: First hit on google: http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/148/topics/4412

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try `gem install bundler`. If that doesn't work my guess would be that you're using two different `ruby` or `rubygems` installations. The user running the webserver does not see the bundler gem.

Comment: "The user running the webserver does not see the bundler gem" - This!
My rubygems is different in the app's ENV than it is for Pow.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running "bundle exec ..." for example: "bundle exec rake -T" instead of just "rake -T".  This makes sure that you are executing the command in the context of gem bundle.

For more info, look at: http://gembundler.com/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need 'bundle install' or forget rake db:migrate command.

Answer (score -1):

If seems that it depends on the user. If you run this command on a ssh access as root user make sure not so use the "sudo" in the front. That fixed it for me.

Comment: Why answer an old already answered questioned with a vague answer?

Comment: because nothing of the above information helped me. Leaving the "sudo" away did the job