# Error with Pow and rbenv - "cannot load such file -- bundler/setup"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv, rack-pow

I know there is an entry on the Troubleshooting [wiki](https://github.com/37signals/pow/wiki/Troubleshooting) page for Pow, but I made that change and it still gives the same error.

If you notice from the error message below, it seems to be at least trying to use the correct version of ruby from rbenv, but still has the same error

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
```

I also looked through all the comments in the [issue](https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/202) mentioned on the troubleshooting page as well and none of those solutions work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, you need a `~/.powconfig` file with:

```
export PATH=$(rbenv root)/shims:$(rbenv root)/bin:$PATH
```

See the [issue discussion](https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/202#issuecomment-2640707) and [the pow guide](https://github.com/37signals/pow/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: A like to use a slight variation on this in order to avoid hardcoding the `.rbenv` path: `export PATH=$(rbenv root)/shims:$(rbenv root)/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely a more robust pattern that I have seen since the time I wrote this answer.  updated

Answer (score 2):

1) cat ~/.powconfig

`export PATH=/Users/alvin/.rbenv/shims:$PATH`

2) restart

`touch ~/.pow/restart.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I had this error using rbenv and simply uninstalling and re-installing pow fixed it:

`curl get.pow.cx/uninstall.sh | sh`

and

`curl get.pow.cx | sh`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For some reason I have two .rbenv shims directories. One in `~/.rbenv/shims` and one in `~/Developer/.rbenv/shims`.

By changing my `~/.powconfig` to add the Developer directories to my path, pow ran the app fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness.

I was having a similar issue and the answer [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691695/pow-not-working-with-ruby-2-0-using-rbenv) fixed it for me.

I had to remove `~/.ruby-version` in order for it to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using rbenv, and had this problem, when as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7270860/1450420), the version of Ruby was different in the app's ENV than it was for Pow.

I had set the Ruby version using the [RBENV_VERSION](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#choosing-the-ruby-version) environment variable, which for some reason was not picked up by Pow.  This was fixed by creating a `.ruby-version` file in the directory of my project.