# Pow not working with Ruby 2.0 using RBENV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv, rack-pow

I installed Ruby 2.0.0-p247 via `rbenv` (ruby-build) and unfortunately my Pow.cx isn't working.

Has anyone had this experience?

I'm getting the following Pow

```
Error starting application
Your Rack app raised an exception when Pow tried to run it.

~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
~/Code/sandwiches_app/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
```

Any insights is much appreciated. It looks like it's looking at the 1.9.3 version of Ruby but I've set the `rbnenv` global, shell and local (within the app .ruby-version) to use Ruby 2.0.0-p247. I'm using ZSH and have tried updating homebrew, rbenv and also a coldboot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like this is an known issue as per: https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/363

I had to delete the file .ruby-version in my home directory ~ for it to work.

I hope this helps people who has experienced the same problem.

Comment: Thank you! I'd been going in circles trying to change `~/.powconfig`

Comment: I use rbenv and for awhile now I could not figure out why my current project .ruby-version was not being picked up by Pow. This worked like a champ, tho it should not have. But thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Ok the above answer does work but for those of you that share a project with others and the option to remove the .ruby-version file is not a possibility....

Add a .powrc file in the root of your project and in that file add this:

```
if [ -f "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm" ]; then
   source "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm"
   rvm use .
fi
```